# Ethereum in Remix contact. Withdrawal doesn't work

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, remix, etherscan

I opened a smart contract on Remix and sent some eth on it. Now that I want to use the withdrawal option to send the Eth back to my Metamask the gas estimation error tells me that I don't have enough eth for profitable frontrunning.
I still went on, knowing that my gas fees will be higher that usual. But when I confirm the withdrawal in Metamask and the transaction is already pending It gets cancelled.

Is somebody here who know what I can do in this situation?

I tried to load some more eth on my Metamask because the estimated fees where about $100 so I uploaded $120 but the only difference were that the withdrawal was pending for 5min longer and then got cancelled.

I thought it would be possible that I got scammed but then I wouldn't see the Ethereum in the contract on Etherscan right?